# Numerical divine connection

Tags: riddle, knowledge, history

All of the following can be connected

1. 4
2. 29 - 32
3. 25
4. 13

to a well known figure. Who can it be and how ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are possibly thinking of

> Jesus of Nazareth, founder of the Christian religion.

4

> is the number of gospels in the New Testament, describing his life, teaching and actions. OR it's the year of his likely birth (4 BCE) -- the way of numbering years common in the West is based around an estimate of his birth date now thought unlikely to be right.

29-32

> is the approximate year of his death.

25

> is the date of the festival of his birth (25th December), although so far as I know no one actually thinks he was really born then.

13

> is the number of people present at the so-called "Last Supper". (This is alleged to be the reason why 13 is considered an unlucky number in many Western cultures.)

It's a "numerical divine connection" because

> Christians consider Jesus to be God incarnate.

Comment: I would say no \*scholars\* really believe 25. I think most laymen actually do.

Comment: @Gareth McCaughan, well, got all correct except the 2nd one, though that is arguable !

Comment: Could about-equally-plausibly be his age at death, I guess.

Comment: The same answer to basically every question in kids' sunday school...

Comment: "Now, children, can you tell me what's small and has a really bushy tail, and buries nuts over the winter?" "I'm sure the answer must be Jesus, but it sounds like a squirrel!"